# Multiple strategies for same function parameter in python hypothesis

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis

I am writing a simple test code in Python using the [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) package. It there a way to use multiple strategies for the same function parameter? As an example, use `integers()` and `floats()` to test my `values` parameter without writing two separate test functions?

```
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import lists, integers, floats, sampled_from
@given(
    integers() ,floats()
)
def test_lt_operator_interval_bin_numerical(values):
    interval_bin = IntervalBin(10, 20, IntervalClosing.Both)
    assert (interval_bin < values) == (interval_bin.right < values)
```

The above code doesn't work, but it represents what i would like to achieve.

NB: I have already tried the trivial solution of creating two different tests with two different strategies:

```
def _test_lt(values):
    interval_bin = IntervalBin(10, 20, IntervalClosing.Both)
    assert (interval_bin < values) == (interval_bin.right < values)

test_lt_operator_interval_bin_int = given(integers())(_test_lt)

test_lt_operator_interval_bin_float = given(floats())(_test_lt)
```

However I was wondering if there was a nicer way to do this: when the nummber of strategies becomes larger, it is quite redundant as code.

Comment: so your values can be either integers() or floats()? if so you can simply do `@given(integers() | floats())`

Comment: Is it possible?? I didn’t know it. if it works, it solved my problem

Comment: Yes, that works!  You can also use `st.one_of(integers(), floats())` which may be easier for programattic use.

Comment: Well you can add an answer and i will accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general if you need your values to be one of several things (like `int`s or `float`s in your example) then we can combine strategies for separate things into one with `|` operator (which operates similar to one for `set`s -- a union operator and works by invoking [`__or__` magic method](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/1336278fb4129fa30d36c894f7e6c73dfc2e357a/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/strategies/_internal/strategies.py#L382-L390)):

```py
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import integers, floats
@given(
    integers() | floats()
)
def test_lt_operator_interval_bin_numerical(values):
    interval_bin = IntervalBin(10, 20, IntervalClosing.Both)
    assert (interval_bin < values) == (interval_bin.right < values)
```

or you can use [`strategies.one_of`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html?highlight=one_of#hypothesis.strategies.one_of) as @Zac Hatfield-Dodds mentioned which does pretty much the same thing:

```py
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import integers, floats, one_of
@given(
    one_of(integers(), floats())
)
def test_lt_operator_interval_bin_numerical(values):
    interval_bin = IntervalBin(10, 20, IntervalClosing.Both)
    assert (interval_bin < values) == (interval_bin.right < values)
```